# Set WAS Process Definition Environment Entries using Jython?

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-6.1

Is it possible to add custom Process Definition environment entry in a WebSphere Application Server using a jython script?

I see that the existing properties in the server.xml are assigned auto-generated IDs, is it possible to retrieve those prop without knowing their ID?

```
 <environment xmi:id="Property_1248356598212" name="<my_prop>" value="<my_value>" required="true"/>
```

WAS 6.1/i5

Answer (score 1):

checkout [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/txml_jvm.html) link for configuring process definition properties using jython

some snippets that might help you

server = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:mycell/Node:mynode/Server:server1/')
processDef = AdminConfig.list('JavaProcessDef', srvid)
print AdminConfig.show(processDef, 'environment')

server = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:mycell/Node:mynode/Server:server1/')
jvm = AdminConfig.list('JavaVirtualMachine', server)
AdminConfig.modify(ns, [['BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS', [['host', 'myhost'],  ['port', 2810]]]])